# What command opens Ruby's REPL?

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop

What command opens Ruby's REPL?

In Python, you simply open `python` without any arguments.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use the `irb` (Interactive Ruby Shell) command.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell

Answer (score 124):

There are several REPLs for Ruby.

The standard library ships with a REPL called *IRb* (for *Interactive Ruby*), which installs a program named `irb`, but since it is just a Ruby library, it can also be invoked from Ruby code and not just from the shell. On [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/), IRb can also be invoked by just calling the `rbx` program without arguments, just like in CPython.

There is also a very nice REPL called [*Pry*](https://pry.github.io/), which installs a program named `pry`, but since it is just a Ruby library, it can also be invoked from Ruby code and not just from the shell.

[JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) comes with an additional REPL called *JIRb Swing*, which is invoked by calling the `jirb_swing` program.

The [NetBeans](http://NetBeans.Org/) Ruby Plugin also comes with a REPL.

Comment: Should this be marked as answer for giving multiple REPLs?

Comment: I like this answer but you could make the default answer (irb) stand out more and then mention the other examples.